# How do I allow users to sort articles by tag with the select field?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 9

I have a view page (*articles*), with a taxonomy term relationship for the *tags* vocabulary. I have no context filters, and the filter criteria are the following.

- Published
- Type: article
- Taxonomy term (exposed) (with relationship "term", "tid" ID, no multiple choice, operator "one of", but I've also tried "all of" with no use)

At first, the article list on page displays correctly, but when I select tag in select-field and press "apply", I get an error.

> InvalidArgumentException: A valid cache entry key is required. Use getAll() to get all table data. in Drupal\views\ViewsData->get() (line 140 of core\modules\views\src\ViewsData.php).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. If you have not done any custom coding, and this is all through the UI, you have likely found a bug, and are not doing anything wrong. As such, you should search for this error in the Drupal issue queue (https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal) and post a bug report there if you do not find anything.

Comment: @Jaypan, thanks for the comment. I'm a newbie in Drupal and actually I would with high probability be able to do something wrong. What I want to do - it's so simple and basic, so I'm sure, that I don't understand something. Could you please explain, how to filter with tags? Or share a link with explanation? I searched, but I didn't find what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four hours later I found what was the mistake.
I shouldn't use any relationship at all. All I need is the filter criteria "Content: Tags (exposed)" with the default settings.